# Watch elements count by class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple HTML:

```
ul > li > button
```

And have some JavaScript code:

```
$('.side-filters .filters_list li').each(function(){
    $(this).find('button').click(function(){

        var arrList = $('.side-filters .filters_list li .active').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active');

        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

If I click on a button, add class 'active' to the button, and if clicked again, remove class.

I need live count elements witn class 'active'. If there is at least one given ul class 'someclass' and if I click again and have no elements with class active, remove 'someclass' from the Ul.

How can I do this?

Comment: post your html here too.

Comment: So what code have you tried to implement this.  The sample shown does not attempt to do this at all.

Comment: You are reinventing toggleClass and you are reading the active class before you add and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop through the elements and add a click to every button. Add one listener.

```
//listen for click on a button
$('.side-filters', "click", ".filters_list li button", function(){

    //toggle the active class on the button
    var button = $(this).toggleClass("active");

    //see if anything is selected
    var hasSelection = $('.side-filters .filters_list li .active').length > 0;

    //toggle a class on the closest ul based on if anything is selected.
    button.closest("ul").toggleClass("someclass", hasSelection);

});
```

References:

- [`toggleClass(class [, switch]`)](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)
- [`.closest( selector )`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this `function ()`

```
function someclass () {
   var count = $('.active').length;
   if (count >= 1) {
       $('ul').addClass('clasHere')
   } else {
       $('ul').removeClass('clasHere')
   }
}
```